# How compile a c++ complex folder with a simple command?

Tags: c++

I have a many c++ files in a folder:

```
> project
  - a.cpp
  - a.h
  - b.cpp
  - b.h
  - main.cpp
  - .editorconfig
  - .gitignore
```

And use this command to compile my code:

```
g++ *.c* -o main
```

However I need organize my code in

```
> project
  > src
    > classes
      - a.h
      - b.h
    > methods
      - a.cpp
      - b.cpp
    - main.cpp

  - .editorconfig
  - .gitignore
```

Some questions:

1 - What command can I use to compile my project?
2 - Is it a good folder structure?

Comment: Use cmake or make. I'll suggest cmake. Common structure would be "include" - with header and "src" - source files.

Comment: One question by question. 1 & 2 are really unrelated.

Comment: *"Is it a good folder structure?"* it is opinion based. split header from source is strange for me. (public) Header directory might make sense for distribution as library. Else I would have tendance to group by "features", so directory `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to compile it with the following command:

```
g++ src/main.cpp src/methods/*.cpp -I src/classes -o myprogram
```

As long as your compilation times are reasonable, there is not much need to use a build system like Make yet.

I don't know if it's a good directory structure, but that's a pretty subjective question.  It's more common to see directories named "include" or "header" than "classes", since it's possible to have header files that do not define classes.  I usually like to put all of the source files in the same directory unless there are a lot of them, or some are written by different teams.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Makefile, then organize your header files in an "include" folder, and your source files in a "src" folder:

```
#change the project to your desired name
EXECUTABLE := project

# the source files to be built
SOURCES := *.cpp


INCLUDES := -I ../include
EXT := out
CC := g++

all:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) $(SOURCES) -o $(EXECUTABLE).$(EXT)

realclean:
    find . -type f -name "*.o" -exec rm '{}' \;
    find . -type f -name "*.exe" -exec rm '{}' \;
    find . -type f -name "*.out" -exec rm '{}' \;
    find . -type f -name "*.gch" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

The makefile will go in your "src" folder, and you would run command "make" to compile and run